# How to parse a $ (dollar) containing field using c#?

Tags: c#, json, bson

Could any one please let me know that how can we parse a field that starts with `$`?

see the sample below,

```
{
    id: 123,
    $firstName: "abc",
    $lastName: "xyz"
}
```

I used to parse it through below object but getting the value empty.

```
var jsonString = "{\"id\": 123,\"$firstName\": \"abc\", \"$lastName\": \"xyz\"}";
var restaurant = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Data>(jsonString);
```

**Data**

```
public class Data
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

`FirstName` and `LastName` are getting `null`

Please advice what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try to apply `JsonProperty` attribute to `Data` class properties. `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$firstname")] public string FristName { get; set; }`.

Comment: And try naming it `FirstName` instead of `FristName`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use `[JsonProperty]`

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$firstName")]
public string firstName{ get; set; }
```